# Updating a column in one table based on criteria in another table SQL Server (Transact-SQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to update the [GradeID](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQShc.png) field in my Employee table based on the employee's salary (grades are pay bands).

The details I need to reference exist in a different [Grade](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W0LXK.png) table.

I tried to update this with the below, but this is not working:

```
UPDATE e
SET e.GradeID = g.gID
FROM Employee e
INNER JOIN Grade g
    ON e.GradeID=g.gID
WHERE e.salary BETWEEN coalesce(g.minSalary, 0) AND coalesce(g.maxSalary, 9999999999)
```

I get the below response, but no fields have been changed:

```
(9 rows affected)

Completion time: ###
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query was not working, because you joined `Employee` and `Grade` on already matching key values.

I would very carefully suggest to join the tables on the condition you specified in the WHERE-clause. (Very carefully, because simply moving conditions from a WHERE-clause to a ON-part of a join in the FROM-clause is generally not a trivial thing to do. In some cases it might impact the meaning and the behavior dramatically. But in this case it would be fine, since its actually your intention to do so.)

Furthermore, I would avoid the `BETWEEN ... AND ...` expression and prefer separate comparisons (`A >= 3 AND A <= 5` instead of `A BETWEEN 3 AND 5`). But that is just personal preference.

More importantly, I would certainly avoid using functions (like `COALESCE`) in any conditions, so that SQL Server can make better use of indexes (when available).

```sql
UPDATE e
SET GradeID = g.gID
FROM Employee e
INNER JOIN Grade g
    ON ((g.minSalary IS NULL OR e.salary >= g.minSalary) AND
        (g.maxSalary IS NULL OR e.salary <= g.maxSalary))
```

**Edit:**

Regarding the use of indexes, [Gordon Linoff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1144035) pointed out to me in the comments to my answer, that the `OR` operator in query criteria would be just as devastating as functions.

I did a short research on the Internet about this, and I found the article ["Avoiding OR for better query performance"](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/avoid-or-for-better-performance/) by Laurenz Albe on the website of Cybertec. It was written for PostgreSQL, however, but I assume that if it does not also apply to SQL Server, it might at least provide a starting point for an investigation that specifically targets SQL Server. And I will keep looking further for SQL Server specific information.

As a possible example of a query structure that avoids `OR` and falls back to functional alternatives, I have rewritten my first query into this:

```sql
UPDATE E
SET GradeID = x.gID
FROM Employee e
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT e.eID, g.gID
  FROM Employee e
  INNER JOIN Grade g
    ON g.minSalary IS NULL AND
       g.maxSalary IS NULL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT e.eID, g.gID
  FROM Employee e
  INNER JOIN Grade g
    ON e.salary >= g.minSalary AND
       g.maxSalary IS NULL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT e.eID, g.gID
  FROM Employee e
  INNER JOIN Grade g
    ON g.minSalary IS NULL AND
       e.salary <= g.maxSalary
  UNION ALL
  SELECT e.eID, g.gID
  FROM Employee e
  INNER JOIN Grade g
    ON e.salary >= g.minSalary AND
       e.salary <= g.maxSalary
) x ON x.eID = e.eID;
```

I only included this alternative query for demonstration purposes. I have not analyzed the performance, because I do not have a matching populated database, of course. So I will leave any desired measurements or query plan investigations up to you. It may also turn out, that four separate UPDATE-queries might be just as fine (and less memory-intensive).

**Tip:**

Note that code is being read way more often than it is being written. So it is important to always create readable and maintainable code. That is especially true for SQL, which is often considered to be very hard to read and understand, even when it is formatted well. Any optimizations should be documented thoroughly. When creating a query, always make a first version that is as straightforward and as simple as possible. After optimization, you could include that simple original query in the query's documentation/comments, which will ease the understanding of the query during future code analysis, maintenance and/or optimization tasks.

Comment: @BartHolland . . . `OR` is going to kill any use of indexes as well, so it is just as bad as `COALESCE()`.  But otherwise the answer is on the mark.

Comment: @GordonLinoff . . . Owww... 8-O... I am quite shocked to learn about issues with indexes regarding using the `OR` operator. Now that I think about it, it does seem pretty plausible, but I cannot remember ever reading anything about it. Thank you very much for this tip. I will certainly try to find more info about this in the Internet. :-)

Comment: @GordonLinoff . . . I am still a little confused about it... Instead of using `SELECT ... WHERE A = X OR (B = Y AND C = Z))`, would it be better to use something like `SELECT ... WHERE A = X UNION SELECT ... WHERE B = Y AND C = Z` with regard to usage of correct indexes??

Comment: . . It is interesting that `union all` can be a better choice with regards to indexes.  Each subquery can be optimized separately.